# GSA: Configure gsa to crawl Open Graph meta-data?

Tags: google-search-appliance

My organization is using gsa version 7.2 Assume that a webpage contains two meta-data:

```
<meta name="Description" content="Test Description"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Test og title"/>
```

From the result of “Index Diagnostics”, I can find meta-data “Description” but cannot find meta-data “og:title”. How could I configure gsa so that meta-data “og:title” also be processed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the GSA can only index metadata with the following format:

```
<meta name="{$name}" content="{$content}"/>
```

The custom tags such as in your example, are not indexable (or at least, yet). In the case you have access to the source code of the website, you could duplicate the unindexable tags with tags with an appropriate structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use metadata-and-url feed to push og:title metadata to GSA.
Refer this [Guide](http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/feedsguide.html) for more information.

Regards,

Mohan